# Как элементу tr дать border-radius + magin-bottom?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста, как элементу tr дать margin-bottom и border-radius? Вот что у меня, не получается закруглить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
  background-color: var(--color-blue);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

td {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 24px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Уборка санузлов</td>
    <td>800 ₽ шт.</td>
    <td>Добавить</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Уборка балкона с мытьем окон</td>
    <td>+ 2000 ₽</td>
    <td>Добавить</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;   
}

tr {
    background-color: var(--color-blue);
    margin-bottom: 8px;    
}

td {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Уборка санузлов</td>
        <td>800 ₽ шт.</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Уборка балкона с мытьем окон</td>
        <td>+ 2000 ₽</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Еще можно это сделать, создав класс, т.к. изначально TR не поддерживает border

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

tr {
    background-color: var(--color-blue);
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: block;
}

td {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 24px;
}

.bordrad {
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr class='bordrad'>
        <td>Уборка санузлов</td>
        <td>800 ₽ шт.</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='bordrad'>
        <td>Уборка балкона с мытьем окон</td>
        <td>+ 2000 ₽</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

UPD:

```css
table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0px 8px;
    }

    tr {
        background-color: #0dcaf0;
    }

    td {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 10px 24px;
    }

    td:first-child {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 10px 24px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

    }
    td:last-child {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 10px 24px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Уборка санузлов</td>
        <td>800 ₽ шт.</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Уборка балкона с мытьем окон</td>
        <td>+ 2000 ₽</td>
        <td>Добавить</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Так класс тогда не нужно указывать, т.к вы сделали tr блочным + у вас текст сьехал, он не равноверно стоит :)

Comment: @KILLER Добавил третий вариант )